# How to integrate Dialogue flow V2 in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am building a chatbot using Dialogflow and i am completely new to this concept as far as the reference website and they had pointed the out the Dialogue flow V1 that has been deprecated right now?

Can you please share some example code on how to interact with the dialogflow API for V2 using Swift?

I tried some code with simple Rest api post request which didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, you can call the [Dialogflow Detect Intent API](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-apple-client) directly from your application using the REST interface. Also, where you need to build your own UI and take care of the authentication process

Whereas the easy process would be to use any third-party tool like [Kommunicate](https://www.kommunicate.io/) where it provides a ready-to-use Swift SDK that already uses pre-configured Dialogflow integration and a dashboard that makes it easy to integrate and build a chatbot. Please check this [link](https://www.kommunicate.io/blog/building-ios-chatbot-with-dialogflow-api-ai/) for more information

PS: I work for Kommunicate

Comment: Thanks i can use Rest api to complete the integration part.